# How to use Button click to open url from xml feed in android

Tags: android, parsing, listview, button, xml-parsing

I have an Rss feed that I have parsed in one activity.  Each item has a seperate url attached to it.  When an item is clicked in the listview it opens into another activity displaying specific text that i have defined from the xml that is being parsed.  I have a button in that view that i would like to assign the url from the xml file for that item.  The only thing i can't figure out is how to string the url information to that button.  here is the code i'm using.

xml parsing activity

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.cpcofc.org/devoapp.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "item";
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
        map.put(KEY_GUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_GUID));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e,KEY_LINK));


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_DESC, KEY_NAME, KEY_COST, KEY_GUID}, new int[] {
                    R.id.desciption, R.id.name, R.id.cost});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Collections.reverse(menuItems);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_GUID));

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_GUID, uriUrl);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
 }
```

Second activity that has the button to view url in it

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    final Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    String uriUrl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_GUID);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);


    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);

Button devo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
devo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);


    }
});
}

}
```

I think my problem lies in this part of the code

```
Button devo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
devo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

but I'm not sure what to put here

```
String url = "what do i put here???";
```

to string the url from the item clicked in the previous screen

this is what the first screen looks like that parses the xml into a listview

[image]

Here is what happens when you click an item in the list view

[image]

log cat

```
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:420)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:410)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at  android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:382)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.SingleMenuItemActivity$1.onClick(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:51)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-13 15:14:31.818: E/AndroidRuntime(8665):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass an Uri Object to a Bundle, a String represenation would be enough

EDIT2:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_GUID));

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);

        // **NEED TO PASS STRING OBJECT NOT URI OBJECT**
        in.putExtra(KEY_GUID, uriUrl.toString());
        startActivity(in);

    }
});
```

EDIT:

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    final Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    final String uriUrl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_GUID);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);


    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);

Button devo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
devo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(uriUrl));
        startActivity(i);


    }
});
}

}
```

**OR**

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";

private String url;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    final Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    url= in.getStringExtra(KEY_GUID);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);


    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);

Button devo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
devo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);


    }
});
}

}
```

Comment: i think i'm passing the information already because it gets the info for the title and description from the xml that has been parsed in the previous activity

Comment: Made an edit, If this is not what you want, i'm not getting what you mean. The requested url is parsed in activity1 and need to be passed to activity2?

Comment: that code crashed it.  you are correct, the requested url is parsed in the first activity and then i need it to be passed to activity 2 so that when the button is clicked it opens the url from the item in activity 1.  does that make since

Comment: What is the stacktrace or exception?

Comment: Try to refernce the String of the extras in onCreate to a member and use it later?

Comment: i think i am referencing it in the oncreate method

Comment: You are defining it locally, you can use the url as a member or you can use the final modifier

Comment: still crashing it on button click, wanna move this to chat and maybe work though it there

Comment: edit, copied all code and applied changes, this will be my last atempt ;)

Comment: ran it just as you have it and it still crashes it

Comment: both versions of the code you posted still crash on button click. I think it is really close though and if you would we can move this to chat and work it together real quick

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22681/discussion-between-user1281750-and-bryan)